# Como agrupar identificadores que são relacionados através de linha e de colunas no R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Olá. Estou trabalhando com linkage de bases e tenho agora 2 colunas de IDs pareados (`id_a` e `id_b`). Cada par representa o mesmo indivíduo localizado em bases diferentes:

```
  id_a <- c(12,15,68663,34,34,34,20,1001) 
  id_b <- c(67764,68663,68667,14,19,1001,20,2112)
  input <- data.frame(id_a,id_b)
```

Assim, o id `15` está relacionado ao id `68663` e também ao id `68667` (via id `68663`); esses 4 ids agrupados referem-se ao mesmo indivíduo.

Preciso desse output:

```
output <- data.frame(id_linked_1 = c(12, 14, 15, 20),
                     id_linked_2 = c(67764, 19, 68663, 20),
                     id_linked_3 = c(NA, 34, 68667, NA),
                     id_linked_4 = c(NA, 1001, NA, NA),
                     id_linked_5 = c(NA, 2112, NA, NA))
```

Ou seja, preciso agrupar todos os pares que estão relacionados. A ordem desse agrupamento não é relevante para a análise.

Exemplo: `15//68663//68667` e `15//68667//68663` são iguais.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução pode ser encontrada com o pacote `igraph`, para problemas de grafos. Parece ser natural tratar do problema da pergunta como sendo um problema de encontrar as componentes conexas de um grafo.

**1.** Carregar o pacote `igraph` e criar um grafo a partir da base.

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(input)
plot(g, vertex.size = 30, vertex.color = 'lightgrey', edge.arrow.width = 0.5)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2.** Agora determinar as componentes. A função `all_simple_paths` é uma opção. Mas vou usar a função `subcomponent` passando cada um dos vértices da primeira coluna da base `input`.

```
v_num <- unique(match(input[[1]], names(V(g))))
path_list <- mapply(subcomponent, list(g), v_num)
names(path_list) <- v_num
```

**3.** Agora, saber quais são únicas, o código acima dá uma componente para cada elemento do vetor `input$id_a`, possivelmente com repetições.
Nota: aqui é chamada a função `str_sort` de mais um pacote externo, `stringr`. Isto serve para ordenar os nomes dos vértices, que são de classes `"character"`, por ordem numérica mas não é absolutamente necessário para o resultado final. A ordem dada pela função base `sort` também serve.

```
path_list2 <- lapply(path_list, function(p){
  p <- unlist(p, recursive = FALSE)
  stringr::str_sort(unique(names(p)), numeric = TRUE)
})

path_list2
#$`1`
#[1] "12"    "67764"
#
#$`2`
#[1] "15"    "68663" "68667"
#
#$`3`
#[1] "15"    "68663" "68667"
#
#$`4`
#[1] "14"   "19"   "34"   "1001" "2112"
#
#$`5`
#[1] "20"
#
#$`6`
#[1] "14"   "19"   "34"   "1001" "2112"
```

**4.** Estes vetores são os vetores do gráfico acima mas há de facto repetições, é preciso ficar com um de cada um desses vetores.

```
final <- lapply(seq_along(path_list2), function(i){
  keep <- sapply(seq_along(path_list2)[-seq_len(i)], function(j){
    length(intersect(path_list2[[i]], path_list2[[j]])) == 0
  })
  if(all(keep)) path_list2[[i]] else NULL
})

final <- final[lengths(final) > 0]
final
#[[1]]
#[1] "12"    "67764"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "15"    "68663" "68667"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "20"
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "14"   "19"   "34"   "1001" "2112"
```

Agora só temos um de cada, que correspondem ao resultado pretendido.

**5.** Com o formato da pergunta.

```
sapply(final, paste, collapse = "//")
#[1] "12//67764"              "15//68663//68667"       "20"                    
#[4] "14//19//34//1001//2112"
```